# Gulp Watch not catching changes in Browserify files

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, browserify, vue.js

I am using the laravel-elixir-vueify npm package.  Gulp watch works fine for me whenever I change a file within the "scripts" or the "styles" functions. However, whenever I change the 1 file I have in the "browserify" function, gulp watch doesn't run. Here is my code:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
        .browserify(['main.js'
        ], './public/js/main.js')

        .scripts([
            'libs/jquery-2.1.1.js',
            'libs/bootstrap.js',
            'libs/vue.js',
        ], './public/js/libs.js')

      .styles([
            'libs/bootstrap.min.css',
            'libs/style.css'
        ], './public/css/libs.css');
});
```

I have also tried just using the below to no avail:

```
mix.sass('app.scss')
        .browserify(['main.js')
(etc...)
```

Not only would I like gulp to run whenever I change anything in main.js, but I have a Vue component file that gets imported into main.js. I change this file frequently, and I would really like gulp watch to catch it when I change that file. Any suggestions?

If the above is impossible, is there a way to run gulp so it only re-compiles the browserify file (and skips the scripts/styles files)?

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.sass('app.scss');

   mix.browserify(['main.js'
    ], './public/js/main.js');

   mix.scripts([
        'libs/jquery-2.1.1.js',
        'libs/bootstrap.js',
        'libs/vue.js',
    ], './public/js/libs.js');

   mix.styles([
        'libs/bootstrap.min.css',
        'libs/style.css'
    ], './public/css/libs.css');
 });
```

remember to write this line of code at your `main.js` file

```
import Vue from 'Vue';
```

and for importing vue components :

```
import YourComponent from './yourPATH/YourComponent.vue';
```

hope it works.

my `gulpfile.js`

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vueify');


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss','resources/css');

    mix.browserify('main.js');

    mix.styles([
        'libs/bootstrap.css',
        'app.css'
    ]);

    mix.scripts([
        'libs/bootstrap.js',
        'libs/jquery-2.2.2.js'
    ]);
});
```

my basic `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'Vue';
import Alert from './components/Alert.vue';

new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    components: {Alert}
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to run just one of those method calls like only mix.browserify(etc...) from the command line?  Something like gulp -browserify?

Comment: I reformatted my code to look exactly like yours, but gulp watch still doesn't run when I change main.js at all.

Comment: Weird, with that convention my scripts and styles merged perfectly and my sass and browserify are perfectly compiled. Did you see any errors when you run `gulp` ?

Comment: Gulp runs fine.  So, if you change your main.js while running "gulp watch", it will run the browserify part mix.browserify(['main.js'
    ], './public/js/main.js')?

Comment: Yes, it will compiles any changes in all parts within elixir method

Comment: Can you edit your above answer to show me exactly what your entire gulpfile.js looks like, as well as your exact and entire main.js file?

Comment: What version of NPM and node do you have installed?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you, but whenever I change anything in main.js or the .vue file, gulp watch still does not catch it when I have it set up exactly as your example above.

Comment: what npm and node version do you use? mine are npm 3.7.5 and node 4.4.2 , it works perfectly fine.